Cycles Transparent BSDF - Minimal Value
Is there a minimum value for transparency of the Transparent BSDF?
I try to make a physical simulation using the Transparent BSDF of Cycles.
Therefore I am converting decibel values to percentage and apply these as Color Input into the Transparent BSDF, e.g. 10dB loss==0.1 transparency, 20dB==0.01 transparency. See image below.
This works great until a hard boundary at 50dB==0.000010 transparency.
Any input value below 0.000010 (50dB) results in total absorption, i.e., full opacity.
Is this a known rounding error or maybe a bit depth resolution problem of the shader?
Thank you for any hints.
Best Regards


Float algebra in Blender is single precision, so 10^{-5} is very close to the round off value.

Thank you for the fast comment. I thought in that direction. Is there an approach to overcome this issue? For rendering / baking i can use float32 values, is there a similar thing for shader "configuration" values?

Have you thought of keeping a linear relation between dB and color? Yeah, might not be physically accurate, but maybe it's enough for visualization? Or you could try to increase your range by taking a square root or using another power.

Since the goal is precise rendering of physical effects, this is a major issue. Not only a visualization problem.

"precise rendering of physical effects"? There is no such thing. At all. Doesn't exist. In any field or in any software. So you will have trouble if that's the goal you have in your mind. It only ever gets precise enough if you are lucky. Choose a higher number to represent lower values maybe, like what you would do with scene units - if you need to work with nanometers, you use Unit Scale and set 1 scene unit to represent 1 nanometer or micrometer instead of a meter and gain precision in scales that matter to you.

Not sure if my fictional example makes sense - who would need to work in nanometers?.. Anyway, if you are making a planet, you scale the units to match kilometers or hundreds of kilometers. That might happen.
